# How to silence "Default will never be executed" in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a switch statement that shows different banners according to a `type` variable.

```
switch type {   
        case HPBannerType.NetworkUnavailableBanner:
            break
        case HPBannerType.LocationServiceUnavailableBanner:
            break
        case HPBannerType.LocationServiceDisabledBanner:
            break  
        default:
            break
}
```

The `type` variable is of type `HPBannerType` which is an enum:

```
enum HPBannerType: String{
    case NetworkUnavailableBanner = "HPNetworkUnavailableBanner"
    case LocationServiceUnavailableBanner = "HPLocationServiceUnavailableBanner"
    case LocationServiceDisabledBanner = "HPLocationServiceDisabledBanner"
}
```

There isn't quite a default type out of 3 types. When I write the switch statement, I have to list all of the cases for clearer understanding. This leaves the ending "default" state an useless state and shows the warning.

```
Default will never be executed
```

How could I silence this warning?

**EDIT:**

@Eric D. has absolute the right solution. But the reason I posted this is because

at first, I did not use the shorthand form `.XXX` but the complete form `HPBannerType.XXX`, when I remove the `default` tag, XCode gave me 200 errors!

So to correct this problem, you HAVE to use shorthand form to allow XCode to recognize if its exhaustive switch statement! Or you will get error. You can try the following:

```
switch type {
        case HPBannerType.NetworkUnavailableBanner:
            break
        case HPBannerType.LocationServiceUnavailableBanner:
            break
        case HPBannerType.LocationServiceDisabledBanner:
            break
 }
```

This will raise error!

Comment: You can even remove the type in the case lines within the switch expression: `case .NetworkUnavailableBanner: break`, the compiler knows the type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to include `default` when switching over your enum because the compiler knows the switch is exhaustive (you've covered all cases):

```
switch type {
case HPBannerType.NetworkUnavailableBanner:
    break
case HPBannerType.LocationServiceUnavailableBanner:
    break
case HPBannerType.LocationServiceDisabledBanner:
    break
}
```

As @vadian commented, you can also use a shorter syntax, because the compiler already knows that `type` is an enum of type `HPBannerType`:

```
switch type {
case .NetworkUnavailableBanner:
    break
case .LocationServiceUnavailableBanner:
    break
case .LocationServiceDisabledBanner:
    break
}
```

Comment: There is only one problem! I will post it in my new edit.

Comment: In short, you *HAVE* to use shorthand form to make compiler know if your switch is exhaustive

Comment: @user3441734 No problem for me either. OP must have had a typo somewhere.